# Sum a comma separated list of numbers using typescript

Tags: typescript, sum

I have a datatable showing some rows and columns that contain some values which user inputs. I want to calculate a sum of columns that are input using typescript but struggling to find the solution:

```
// class
export class DataTable {
    public constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public readonly id: string;
    public rowCount: number = 0;
    public columnCount: number = 0;
}
```

import { DataTable } from "../DataTable/DataTable"

```
export default
    {
        data() {
            return {
                table: new DataTable("ABC"),

                tableId: "",

                columnName: "",

                columnValuesAsCsv: "",

                rowValuesAsCsv: "",

            }
        },

        methods:
        {
            onNewTable() {
                console.log(`New Table: ${this.tableId}`);
                // this.table....
            },

            onAddColumn() {
                console.log(`AddColumn: ${this.columnName} = ${this.columnValuesAsCsv}`);
                // this.table....
            },

            onAddRow() {
                console.log(`Add Row: ${this.rowValuesAsCsv}`);
                // this.table....
            },

            onSum() {
                if (this.columnValuesAsCsv !== null) {
                  let columnSum = this.columnValuesAsCsv.split(",");
                  columnSum = this.columnValuesAsCsv.reduce((acc: number, item: string) => acc += parseInt(item), 0);
                  console.log(columnSum);
                } else {
                    console.log('There are no column numbers entered');
                }
            },
        }
    }
```

And I have some forms and buttons in place in html for UI where a user can create some rows and columns in console and then calculate the sum. Currently I get 01,2,3 as sum results and 0 if there are no columns added instead of that string message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple `reduce` would help

```js
...
onSum() {
  if (this.columnValuesAsCsv !== null) {
    const columnSum = this.columnValuesAsCsv.reduce((acc, item) => acc += parseInt(item), 0);
    console.log(columnSum);
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

also you need to parse the strings into ints

Comment: Tried using reduce before by searching for answers and now with your solutions and get this error: "TypeError: this.columnValuesAsCsv.reduce is not a function"

Comment: What is the type of `this.columnValuesAsCsv` when you hover over it? It sounds like a string so you might need to perform a `.split()` operation

Comment: Yes its a type of string. I have updated my original post with a new solution using split method before reduce, but I still get the same error about reduce not being a function?

Comment: You split the `columnValuesAsCsv` and save it into `columnSum` which means that the `columnSum` is an array now and the `columnValuesAsCsv` is still a string. The `reduce` is being performed on that string. So you need to perform `reduce` on `columnSum` instead

Comment: I had to create an array after using split with Array.from(), split alone wasn't enough. Thanks for the help Anzor, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working, here is the final result:

```
onSum() {
        if (this.columnValuesAsCsv !== null) {
            let columnSum = this.columnValuesAsCsv.split(",");
            let arrNumbers = Array.from(columnSum);
            let resSum = arrNumbers.reduce((acc: number, item: string) => acc += parseInt(item), 0);
            console.log(`Sum of column values is: ${resSum}`);
        } else {
            console.log('There are no column numbers entered');
        }
    },
```